# Soundtrap unexpected change from continuous to short duty cycle recordings

Tags: soundtrap

I am working with Soundtrap 4300s and noticed that the recording was interrupted towards the end of the deployment/recording period. The recorders were set to continuous recording at a high sample rate, and recordings were good for around 3-4 days. It then switched to 16 second files with 4 second gaps between the files.

The battery voltage for both soundtraps did not drop below 3.2 volts.

I have had this happen on two soundtraps inconsistently in both bench and field tests. I have included a figure of QAQC plots for an interrupted recording and a good recording, both from the same soundtrap on two different deployments.

The figure includes a wav file size plot, a file gap plot, and a battery/temperature plot. The drastic change in wav file sizes and gaps between files indicate when the recording was interrupted, initially I thought this may be a battery issue. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue with soundtraps?
[image]

Comment: I haven't experienced this...but just brainstorming...does it happen after a large number of files has been written? Could it have something to do with the write process, like it has to read/access a long list of files to add to and that is slowing down the write process causing a gap?

Answer (score 2):

We have gotten similar results towards the end of the battery life of the instruments.